# Write old fasta header and new to file

Tags: perl, fasta

I want to extract the old fasta names which looks something like this:

```
>Bartonella bibbi
AUUCCGGUUGAUCCUGCCGGAGGCCACUGCUAUCGGGGUCCG
```

The new headers should look like this:

```
>Seq1
AUUCCGGUUGAUCCUGCCGGAGGCCACUGCUAUCGGGGUCCG
```

and so on...
The Bartonella Bibbi should be saved together with the new name Seq1 in a new file an so on. So I've started a bit, by looking for lines with >, and then I split to get an array to get the old name. I don't know how to continue, because I want two things here, first to put the new name in there, but also extracting the old name together with the new in a file, and ALSO get an output file with my sequence and my new names. Please, any input from you will help!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $infile = $ARGV[0];
open my $IN, '<', $infile or die "Could not open $infile: $!, $?";

while (my $line = <$IN>) {
 if ($line =~ /^>/) {

my @header = split (/\>/, $line);

    my $oldfasta = "$header[1]";

}
}
```

So after some edits, this is the current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $infile = $ARGV[0];
open my $IN, '<', $infile or die "Could not open $infile: $!, $?";

my $seqid = 1;
my %id;

while (my $line = <$IN>) {
 if ($line =~ /^>/) {

     $id{"Seq$seqid "} = $line;
     print ">Seq$seqid\n";
     $seqid++
 } else {

     print $line;
 }


}

     my $outfile = 'output';
     open my $OUT, '>', $outfile or die "Could not open $outfile: $!, $?";  # overwrites the file $outfile;
     print $OUT %id;
```

This gives me a file that looks like this:

```
   Seq29  >Sulfophobococcus_zilligii

   Seq20 >Pyrococcus_shinkaii
```

and so on.
They are not in order, how do I sort them and get rid of the > in the species name?

Answer (score 0):

You’re simply not printing anything. Once you add a `print` statement, it should work.

In addition, it’s unclear what you’re using `split` for. Just increase a counter for the sequence:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $infile = $ARGV[0];
open my $IN, '<', $infile or die "Could not open $infile: $!, $?";

my $seqid = 1;

while (my $line = <$IN>) {
    if ($line =~ /^>/) {
        print ">Seq$seqid\n";
        $seqid++;
    } else {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Thank you! So before I replace the headers I should store the old headers somehow in a file, right? That's why I wanted to use split (maybe wrong way to do it), to extract the old name and place them I hashes.

Comment: @Michelangelo Ah, it wasn’t clear that you want to preserve the old headers. You can do that but you don’t need to use `split`. Simply remove the leading `>` by running `$line =~ s/^>//;` and then storing `$line` in an array or a hash. If you want to preserve the header *in the file* and simply prefix it with the sequence ID you can replace `'>'` by {`'>'`, followed by the sequence ID}. This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write the new entries as you create them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $infile = $ARGV[0];
open my $IN, '<', $infile or die "Could not open $infile: $!, $?";
my $outfile = 'output';
open my $OUT, '>', $outfile or die "Could not open $outfile: $!, $?";  # overwrites the file $outfile;

my $seqid = 1;

while (my $line = <$IN>) {
     if ($line =~ /^>(.+)/) {
        print $OUT "Seq$seqid\t$1\n"
        print ">Seq$seqid\n";
        $seqid++
     } else {
        print $line;
     }
}
```

I tried to fix the indentation but left the gratutious variable for the `$OUT` file name.

If you want to keep the mapping in memory for other reasons (maybe to develop this into a much more complex script) using an array instead of a hash would seem like a natural way to keep the entries sorted; the new label is trivially derivable from the array index.